# MySQL Join with a subquery to select only one row from joined table

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

Suppose there are two tables:

Table Parts:

```
Location PartNum Descrip  
-------- ------- --------
Whse1    abc     Frobbitz
Whse2    abc     Frobbitz
Whse3    def     Widget
Whse3    def     Widget
```

Table Status:

```
Location  PartNum Status
--------- ------- --------------
*Default* abc     Ready To Ship
*Default* def     Ready To Ship
Whse1     abc     Backordered
```

In most cases, the default status should be used.

To get the status, the query might look like:

```
SELECT p.Location,p.PartNum,p.Descrip,s.Status FROM Parts p
LEFT JOIN Status s ON s.PartNum=p.PartNum AND
s.Location = (SELECT MAX(Location) FROM Status s1
WHERE s1.PartNum=p.PartNum AND s1.Location
IN('*Default*',p.Location))
```

The question is, is this the most efficient (or at least reasonably efficient) way of doing this? My actual application will have up to 7 tables joined in a single query.

Comment: So, are any of the three answers below a better method than the one in my question? After all, my question was "is this the most efficient (or at least reasonably efficient) way of doing this?"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Limit` 1 with `Order by` as below:

```
 SELECT p.Location,p.PartNum,p.Descrip,s.Status FROM Parts p
  LEFT JOIN Status s ON s.PartNum=p.PartNum AND
  s.Location = (SELECT Location FROM Status s1
        WHERE s1.PartNum=p.PartNum ORDER BY s1.Location ASC LIMIT 1);
```

Assuming `*Default*` will come at the top in order by retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.Location,p.PartNum,p.Descrip,s.Status FROM Parts p
LEFT outer JOIN Status s ON s.PartNum=p.PartNum 
where
s.Location = (SELECT MAX(Location) FROM Status s1
WHERE s1.PartNum=p.PartNum AND s1.Location
IN('*Default*',p.Location))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears like what you are trying to do is use a fallback default. You could try something like joining the table twice instead of using a subquery:

```
SELECT p.Location,p.PartNum,p.Descrip,s.Status 
FROM Parts p 
LEFT JOIN Status s1 ON s1.PartNum=p.PartNum AND p.Location = s1.Location 
LEFT JOIN Status s ON p.PartNum = s.PartNum 
   AND s.Location = IFNULL(s1.Location, '*Default*');
```

Essentially, `s1` represents the non-default information. By checking whether `s1.Location` is `NULL` or not, we can tell if such a row exists and fallback to `*Default*` if it doesn't.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That may come down to what Keys and Indices you have. You can check out information about queries by using `EXPLAIN` (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). Personally, I avoid subqueries when possible. It's been my experience that creating the temporary storage for subqueries, specifically for larger result sets, slows down execution a lot.